# How to auto-vectorize range-based for loops?

Tags: c++, vectorization, visual-studio-2013

A similar question was posted on SO for g++ that was rather vague, so I thought I'd post a specific example for VC++12 / VS2013 to which we can hopefully get an answer.

> **cross-link:**
>   [g++ , range based for and vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688419/g-range-based-for-and-vectorization)

MSDN gives the following as an example of a loop that can be vectorized:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
{       
    A[i] = A[i] + 1;
}
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj658585.aspx)

Here is my version of a range-based analogue to the above, a c-style monstrosity, and a similar loop using `std::for_each`. I compiled with the **/Qvec-report:2** flag and added the compiler messages as comments:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(1000, 1);

    // simple range-based for loop
    {
        for (int& elem : vec)
        {
            elem = elem + 1;
        }
    } // info C5002 : loop not vectorized due to reason '1304'

    // c-style iteration
    {
        int * begin = vec.data();
        int * end = begin + vec.size();

        for (int* it = begin; it != end; ++it)
        {
            *it = *it + 1;
        }
    } // info C5001: loop vectorized

    // for_each iteration
    {
        std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int& elem)
        {
            elem = elem + 1;
        });
    } // (no compiler message provided)

    return 0;
}
```

Only the c-style loop gets vectorized. Reason 1304 is as follows as per [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj658585.aspx):

> 1304: Loop includes assignments that are of different sizes.

It gives the following as an example of code that would trigger a 1304 message:

```
void code_1304(int *A, short *B)
{
    // Code 1304 is emitted when the compiler detects
    // different sized statements in the loop body.
    // In this case, there is an 32-bit statement and a
    // 16-bit statement.

    // In cases like this consider splitting the loop into loops to 
    // maximize vector register utilization.

    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
    {
        A[i] = A[i] + 1;
        B[i] = B[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

I'm no expert but I can't see the relationship. Is this just buggy reporting? I've noticed that none of my range-based loops are getting vectorized in my actual program. What gives?

(In case this is buggy behavior I'm running VS2013 Professional Version 12.0.21005.1 REL)

**EDIT: Bug report posted: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807826/range-based-for-loops-are-not-vectorized**

Comment: Are you compiling for release mode?

Comment: @dauphic yes, 64-bit with /Ox optimization. Why do you ask?

Comment: Does it vectorize if you change from `int` to `long long`? Also try with a 32-bit build.

Comment: @ausairman What if you rewrite the `for` in a couple of different ways? First iterate over [`vec[0]`, `vec.size()`) and assign using `op[]`. Next, try iterating over [`begin(vec)`, `end(vec)`) and assign by dereferencing the iterator. The second case should be analogous to the range-based `for`.

Comment: I'd say it is a good reason for the back-end guys to have a meeting with the front-end guys.  Auto-vectorization was developed before the front-end was ready to tackle C++11.  Use connect.microsoft.com to report this.

Comment: @Praetorian I've added some other loops, it works for a c-style version but doesn't report anything for `std::for_each` (presumably this is expected behavior)

Comment: @HansPassant ok i'll report it...

Comment: Ok report posted at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807826/range-based-for-loops-are-not-vectorized please upvote if you can reproduce this.

Comment: I suggest using the ICC compiler for now until the VC compiler get's updated at the end of the year. http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-compilers

Comment: @Damian offtopic - how do you know they're updating at the end of the year? Do they publish that information somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posted bug report here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807826/range-based-for-loops-are-not-vectorized

Response:

> Hi, thanks for the report.
>
> Vectorizing range-based-for-loop-y code is something we are actively
>   making better. We'll address vectorizing this, plus enabling
>   auto-vectorization for other C++ language & library features in future
>   releases of the compiler.
>
> The emission of reason code 1304 (on x64) and reason code 1301 (on
>   x86) are artifacts of compiler internals. The details of that, for
>   this particular code, is not important.
>
> Thanks for the report! I am closing this MSConnect item. Feel free to
>   respond if you need anything else.
>
> Eric Brumer Microsoft Visual C++ Team